# Painting exhaust on motorcycle

Tags: honda, motorcycle, exhaust, paint, shadow

I recently purchase an 07 Honda shadow spirit and it has chrome exhaust, could anyone tell me how I could paint them black, thank you

Comment: I painted exhaust manifolds with high temperature paint - looked great. After the first engine run to hot it no longer did . High temperature paint isn't...

Comment: Chrome has to be sand blasted before any paint will stick well.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use a product like [Cerakote High Temp](https://www.cerakote.com/finishes/?tab=coatings&cat=GLACIER) coatings which is good up 1800°F. It is made specifically for automotive exhaust parts. It's also UV stable and is extremely corrosion resistant. To get it to stick, just use some Scotchbrite pads prior to painting to scuff it up. Most anything else isn't going to be able to stand up to the thermals of an exhaust pipe without peeling off or becoming very discolored.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your solution on your local hardware store. 
You should ask for high temperature spray paint (usually found in black color). 
It will leave a nice matte finish on your pipes after application. 
For a better application that will last longer you might need to sandpaper your pipes thoroughly first and rub them with some alcohol solution prior to painting to remove any leftover grease. 
With 2-3 hands of coat you should be fine.